# How to make Accessibility reader also announce the pressed state of a view

Tags: android, accessibility

I am using an image view to act as a button. When the image view is clicked it changes color of background to orange and remains in this state. From accessibility point of view I need to also make the reader call out the pressed state (i.e. whether its already in pressed state or not). How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a trait that can be set on Android for a "pressed" state. Are you already using `android:contentDescription` on the image view to label your button?  You might have to append the description with "pressed".  On iOS, there are separate `accessibilityLabel` and `accessibilityHint` attributes so it allows you to put the "pressed" state in the "hint".  But I can't find a similar separation of label and hint for android.

(There is an `android:hint` but it's only for TextViews and is analogous to placeholder text.  It's not a hint for screen readers to announce as a description.)

Comment: Hi Slugolicious, thanks for your help. Actually good thing is when i am setting image view to pressed state or selected state for e.g imageView.setPressed(true), accessibility takes care of announcing 'pressed' too. Hence, its solved.